# basic understanding of hereditary property in matroid

Tags: algorithms, terminology, definition, matroids

I'm trying to prove something is a matroid and to do that I must understand what a matroid is. I don't get the hereditary property.

> A matroid is an ordered pair $(S, I)$. I is a non-empty family of
>   subsets of $S$ such that if $B \in I$ and $A \subset B$ then $A \in I$

I try understanding this with an example. Let $S=\{2,3,5,9,7\}$ then let $I=\{2,3\}$. For any $A \subset B$ then of course it's going to be in  $I$ e.g. $2$ and $3$ are in $B$ and $I$.

I'm assuming I don't understand the definition. Could someone provide a simple example that meats the hereditary property and does not? I don't fully understand the difference between subset ($\subset$) and in ($\in$).

Comment: $I$ is a non-empty family of *subsets* of $S$.  The $I$ you have chosen is a subset of $S$, not a family of subsets such as $\{\{2,3\}\}$ or .$\{\{2\},\{3\}\}$.

Comment: So if I just put $\{\}$ around ${2,3}$ my example would be right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "would be right".  You would need to rethink about how the definition applies to this new choice of $S$.  It isn't just a matter of notation; putting braces around $\{2,3\}$ gives you an entirely different set (which has only one element instead of two).

Answer (score 1):

$I$ has to be a set of subsets of $S$, e.g. something like

$$I = \{\{2\}, \emptyset\}.$$

Usually, the sets contained in $I$ are called *independent*. The hereditary property means that the subset of every independent set again is independent.

You can think of $I$ this way: You have some set $S$ and want to define (however you like) what it means for a subset of $S$ to be independent. You can do this either by giving some formula/condition every subset has to satisfy or you just explicitly list all independent subsets.

Now, some smart minds came to the conclusion that calling a property of sets *independence* only makes sense if the collection of these sets is a matroid, i.e. if

1. Every subset of an independent set is again independent **and**
2. if an independent set $A$ is smaller than an independent set $B$, we can add some element of $B$ (which is not already in $A$) to $A$ and get another independent set.